# Use param but save $args in powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to have a script update itself, and then relaunch itself.

The problem occurs when the script tries to pass parameters to itself, as apparently using `param` clears `$args`. I had an idea to make a custom `$args`-handler that works like `param`, but is there a better way? I do need the arguments to be named so some handling is necessary, I can't just use `$args`.

```bsh
param(
    $a = "abc",
    $b,
    $c
)

Write-Host $a
Write-Host $b
Write-Host $c

Write-Host $args
```

This results in the following:

```
.\a.ps1 -a 1 -b 2 3
1
2
3
```

Writing the `$args` to host returns nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Taking your problem statement:

> I'm trying to have a script update itself, and then relaunch itself.

This is the purpose of the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable:

```
.\myscript.ps1 @PSBoundParameters
```

And your other issue:

> when the script tries to pass parameters to itself, as apparently using param clears $args

This is untrue.  The issue in your example is *positionally-bound* parameter binding in action.  What actually happens is the `3` gets bound to `$c`.  `$args` will capture unbound parameters unless you have a parameter with the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` attribute.  You can stop this binding from occurring by using the `CmdletBinding` attribute:

```
function Verb-Noun {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
    param(
```

As [`@mklement0`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) points out, you cannot use `$args` in *advanced functions*, where you're using `CmdletBinding` or `Parameter` attributes, like my example above.

---

Docs:

[`about_Automatic_Variables#args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#args)

[`about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-5.1)

[`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1):

`$args` are only available for the unbound parameters you pass into your script. Once you start binding params, each param you pass in to your script will be bound based on its value, type or position.  Anything not matching your param binding will end up in `$args`

Let's say I have a script like this

```
#$args.ps1
write-host "args value 1 : $($args[0]) "
write-host "args value 2 : $($args[1]) "
```

When I call it, I can index into `$args` and pull the values out.

```
& C:\temp\args.ps1 'SomeValue1' 'SomeValue2'
args value 1 : SomeValue1 
args value 2 : SomeValue2
```

However, once I bind params, `$args` will then only contains values which don't match your bindings.  Notice that only the *third param* I pass in below ends up in `$args`

```
param($param1, $param2)
write-host "params value 1 : $($param1) "
write-host "params value 2 : $($param2) "

write-host "args value 1 : $($args[0]) "
write-host "args value 2 : $($args[1]) "
```

Now you'll some interesting behavior when I pass in additional params here.

```
& C:\temp\args.ps1 'SomeValue1' 'SomeValue2' 'SomeValue3'
params value 1 : SomeValue1 
params value 2 : SomeValue2 
args value 1 :  SomeValue3
args value 2 :
```

#### why is it this way?

Think about it like this: as we can see in the help under `get-help about_automatic_variables`, $args is provided to map the **undeclared parameters** passed into a script.  The second you begin declaring parameters, you are specifically describing which params your script will use, and `$args` becomes a bit weird in usage.

> $Args
>          Contains an array of the **undeclared parameters** and/or parameter
>          values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
>          When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
>          param keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
>          parentheses after the function name.

*thanks @LotPings for the correction on the behavior of `$args`, I originally posted in error that `$args` contians nothing if you bind params.

Comment: i think what you want in this case is `$PsBoundParameters`. [*grin*]

Comment: You should rework your 1st sentence, `$Args` contains all unbound parameters, it's not an either/or if there are more parameters than declared via params they can be retrieved from `$args` provided there is no `param([string[]] [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)] $Remaining)`

Comment: Good point, I actually never realized that before.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to change the values of the parameters, you might just fetch the arguments from the raw command line:

```
Write-Host ($MyInvocation.Line -split '\.ps1[\s\''\"]\s*', 2)[-1])
```

<sub>(Or just re-invoke the whole command line in once, but you will need to prevent an infinitive loop somehow)</sub>